# How to use a DLL in VBA without registering it?

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, vba, soap

This is in reference to two other SO questions I've posted: [adding items to a Sharepoint list with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147731/how-to-add-items-to-a-sharepoint-list-using-excel-vba) and [calling UpdateListItems from VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092273/what-arguments-does-updatelistitems-take-when-calling-sharepoint-web-service-fro).

I want to update a Sharepoint list with a new data row based on results of some Excel calculations.  My current approach is a SOAP call to the Sharepoint site's Web Service.  I've successfully done this on my local machine using the SOAP 3.0 library.  Problem is that this is a shared spreadsheet among 20-30 users, so I don't want a solution that requires each of them to register a DLL.

I tried placing the MSSOAP30.DLL in the same folder as the shared spreadsheet, and then adding it as a reference by browsing to it.  Ran the following code:

```
Sub test()

Dim soap As MSSOAPLib30.SoapClient30
Dim XMLstr As String
Dim listid As String
Dim listname As String

Set soap = New SoapClient30
Call soap.mssoapinit(par_wsdlfile:="http://wss/mySharepointSite/_vti_bin/lists.asmx?wsdl")


listid = "{e285aa1a-my-list-ID-d446cdbf091e}"
listname = "thisList"

XMLstr ="<Batch OnError='continue' ListVersion='1' ViewName='" & ListView & "'>" & _   
        "<Method ID='1' Cmd='New'>" & _
            "<Field Name='ID'>New</Field>" & _
            "<Field Name='personID'>1337</Field>" & _
        "</Method>"
        "</Batch>"

soap.UpdateListItems listid, XMLstr

End Sub
```

But when I ran the code, `soap.UpdateListItems` gives the following error:

```
Run-time error '-2147221164 (80040154)':

Client:The connector could not be created.  There might be an invalid endPoint specified in the WSDL file HRESULT=0x80040154: Class not registered
-Client:Unspecified client error. HRESULT=0x80040154: Class not registered
```

Again, this code works fine on my local machine where I've registered MSSoap 3.0.  Maybe browsing to the MSSOAP30.DLL reference isn't sufficient to properly define the `SoapClient30` object?  I saw that there are a lot of other DLLs in the \MSSoap\Binaries folder, do I need to include references to all of those as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this without using another DLL, just using an XMLHTTP POST operation.  Solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092273/what-arguments-does-updatelistitems-take-when-calling-sharepoint-web-service-fro/11125010).

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid although its technically possible (with a substantial amount of Jiggery Pockery - yes an official technical term) its not really viable to try to use a COM dll without registration.

A simple script downloaded to each client would register the dll very quickly.